# Impact of convexity under different changes of variables for different parts of optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constraints

Let 
$$
\min_x f(x)$$
such that
$$
 C(x) \le 0$$
where $C$, and $f$ each are convex under respective changes of variables.

How does that impact the optimization?
If standard algorithms are sensitive to this, would it be possible to exploit the convexity nonetheless?

Comment: What do you mean by "under respective changes of variables", specifically?

Comment: @MichaelGrant, I mean that two coordinate transformations $h: y\mapsto x$ and $g: z \mapsto x$ lead to $f(h(y))$ and $C(g(z))$ being convex. For instance $C(x)=\|x\|^{-1}-1, x\in \mathbb{R}^3$ becomes convex in spherical coordinates, whereas $f(x)=(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{-1} + x_3$ is convex in cylindrical coordinates but not in spherical coordinates (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: I see. I'm going to guess that the answer is no. I'm sure we agree that if there were one transformation that works for all of the functions, such as the convex transformation of geometric programs, you'd be in business. But with a separate transformation required for each function, I don't think you can exploit that.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, the reason why I think that something might be there is because I blithely put in $C(x)=\|x\|^{-1}-1\le 0$ as a constraint into IPOPT for a toy problem and it performed much better than I expected.

Comment: The funny thing about nonconvex optimization is that it often works... :-)

Comment: @MichaelGrant, and now off to characterize why and when :-)